# What is the best way to write critical nodejs backend functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write functions for repeating tasks. So for example I want to have a file lib/dbFunctions to handle anything with my database, like searching the databse for a specific user.
so I just want to create the function searchUser(username) and just import my functions with e.g. `const dbFunctions = require('lib/dbFunctions`), so I can call `dbFunctions.searchUser("ExampleUser");`

How would I solve this in NodeJS?

I only found examples using the `express.Router()` looking like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const customRoutes = express.Router();
cusrtomRoutes.get('/login',function(req,res){
    res.render('account/login');
});
module.exports = {"CustomRoutes" : customRoutes};
```

However I somehow couldn't figure out how to write a completly custom class with functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to know how to make a module.

Say you have an `index.js` like this:

```
const dbFunctions = require('./lib/dbFunctions')

console.log(dbFunctions.searchUser('Dan'))
```

You can make your module work by creating a file at `<project_root>/lib/dbFunctions.js` which can look like this:

```
const searchUser = (name) => `found user ${name}`

module.exports = {searchUser}
```

Now if you run `node index.js` you'll see `found user Dan` print in your console.

It's important to note that when you're importing modules node expects a path like `lib/dbFunctions` to exist inside `node_modules` whereas when you're trying to import a local module within your project you need to specify the relative path from where you're importing hence I used `./lib/dbFunctions` in my example.

Another common way to create a custom lib in your project is using a pattern called barrel files or barrel exports.

Instead of having a file called `dbFunctions.js` you'd create a directory at `/lib/dbFunctions` with an `index.js` inside the root of that directory. You can then seperate out all of your functions into their own modules like this for example:

```
// /lib/dbFunctions/searchUser.js
const searchUser = (name) => `found user ${name}`

module.exports = searchUser

// /lib/dbFunctions/searchPost.js
const searchPost = (id) => `found post ${id}`

module.exports = searchPost
```

And then your `index.js` file would look like this:

```
// /lib/dbFunctions/index.js
const searchUser = require('./searchUser');
const searchPost = require('./searchPost');

module.exports = {
    searchUser,
    searchPost
}
```

Then your main entry point (`index.js`)

```
const dbFunctions = require('./lib/dbFunctions')

console.log(dbFunctions.searchUser('Dan'))
console.log(dbFunctions.searchPost(2))
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the closest to what I am searching for (and js has to offer). Do you aswell have an idea what I can do to keep my connection to the database? The problem seems to be with this method that I either need to create a new mysql.createConnection() or always parse the connection like 'searchUser(name,con)'
I somehow expected that I can have my own class and keep the connection I create at the beginning. But this doesn't seem to work with modules (or at least I didn't found any method)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) I spend most of my server-side development in PHP land these days but in general the ORM's I work with create a new connection per query, insert or update. Usually the library you use will remove the need to specify the connection so you're not constantly repeating yourself everywhere.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is decouple your domain from your database layer you can of course follow a repository pattern. It sounds like you might not be coming from a JS background so just note that you don't need Classes and Interfaces (native JS doesn't have Interfaces anyway) to create classical OOP patterns. Unless you're using experimental features like decorators for automatic dependency injection I haven't found much use for using classes in JS myself. That said, you might want to check out https://nestjs.com/ if you're looking for something more complete and opinionated.

Comment: The mysql library allows me to use one connection. However I think I need to parse it via 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({[config]});
searchUserByName(name, connection);

At least I don't see any other way (or use const connection = mysql.createConnection({[config]}); at the beginning of every function)

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear Have you considered using mysql pooling connections, with `connectionLimit` set to 1? It will manage your connections for you.https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Answer (score 2):

I usually do such kind of stuff by making a class such as `UserRepository`.

```
class UserRepository() {
  static searchUser(user){
    // your logic here
  }

  static getUserByEmail(email){
    // your logic here
  }
}

module.exports = UserRepository;
```

You can call this function from anywhere like this:

```
const UserRepository = require('./user-repository.js');
UserRepository.searchUser(user);
```

The advantage of above approach is that you can process other logic in constructor which would be require before talking to the database. This is OOP based approach basically.

The other way is (not OOP based):

```
const searchuser = (user) => {};
const getUserByEmail = (email) => {};

module.exports = {
  searchuser,
  getUserByEmail,
};
```

You can use in the same way:

```
const UserRepository = require('./user-repository.js');
UserRepository.search(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to create a module consisting of a bunch of functions. If that's the case, a typical module of functions looks like this:

```js
// file customFunctions.js

function custom1 () { ... }
function custom2 () { ... }
...

module.exports = { custom1, custom2, ... }
```

The module exports an object containing functions as properties.

Then, just require that file where you need it:

```
const customFns = require('./customFunctions');

customFns.custom1();
```